# Как получить таблицу с помощью вызова хранимой процедуры у которой более одного параметра

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо из одной ХП вызвать другую и получить в результате таблицу.

Мои действия:

```
declare @resultMoneyDms Table(Closing_Year int, Closing_Month int, mm_Amount int)
                insert into @resultMoneyDms EXEC MoneyDmsInfo @EndDate = '2017-12-14T00:00:00', @Type = 'Billed'
```

Выдается следующая ошибка :

`Procedure or function MoneyDmsInfo has too many arguments specified.`

Однако вызываемая ХП содержит и использует все передаваемые параметры

Вызываемая ХП:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MoneyDmsInfo] @EndDate DateTime, @Type nvarchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      IF @Type = 'Billed' 
      begin

      declare @DmsBilled Table (Closing_Year int, Closing_Month int, mm_Amount int)

      insert into @DmsBilled SELECT Closing_Year = DATEPART(YEAR, FO.DocDate), Closing_Month = DATEPART(MONTH, FO.DocDate), sum(FO.Amount) AS mm_Amount
      FROM
          [BillLine] AS B
        INNER JOIN [FinOperation] AS FO ON 
          B.ID = FO.ID
        LEFT JOIN [SaleContract] AS SC ON 
          FO.[AgreementID] = SC.ID
        LEFT JOIN [FinSource] AS a3 ON 
          SC.[FinSourceID] = a3.ID
      WHERE FO.DocDate BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND @EndDate and  a3.FinSourceType in (6,7) 
      group by DATEPART(YEAR, FO.DocDate), DATEPART(MONTH, FO.DocDate)
      order by DATEPART(YEAR, FO.DocDate), DATEPART(MONTH, FO.DocDate)
select * from @DmsBilled

  end
```

......

Попробовал вызвать данную процедуру через автосгенерированный код MSSQL Studio
студия предлагает след. код:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[MoneyDmsInfo]
        @EndDate = '2017-12-14T00:00:00',
        @Type = 'Billed'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Но и здесь когда я пытаюсь заменить `DECLARE    @return_value int` на тип Table возникает ошибка `Must declare the scalar variable "@return_value".`

Суть в том, что мне необходимо получить из вызова процедуры с двумя и более параметрами тип Table. 
Где здесь может быть ошибка ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у Вас ошибка в тексте процедуры, который Вы привели. Там как минимум не хватает завершающего «END»! Во-вторых, ваши фрагменты работают, если исправить процедуру (текст запроса из процедуры я естественно не рассматривал, так как нет этих таблиц).

Следующий код у меня прекрасно работает как на SQL Server 2005, так и на SQL Server 2017.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestSP1]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP1] AS' 
END
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP1]
     @EndDate datetime
    ,@Type    nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Type = 'Billed'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DmsBilled TABLE ([Closing_Year]  int
                                 ,[Closing_Month] int
                                 ,[mm_Amount]     int);

        insert into @DmsBilled
        select 1, 1, 1
        union all
        select 2, 2, 2

        select * from @DmsBilled
    END
END
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestSP2]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP2] AS' 
END
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP2]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @resultMoneyDms TABLE ([Closing_Year]  int
                                  ,[Closing_Month] int
                                  ,[mm_Amount]     int);

    INSERT @resultMoneyDms
      EXEC [dbo].[TestSP1]
           @EndDate = '2017-12-14T00:00:00'
          ,@Type    = 'Billed'

    SELECT *
      FROM @resultMoneyDms
END
GO
EXEC [dbo].[TestSP2]
```